# Automatically resolve undefined references from missing library with stubs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, mingw

I am building some unit testing stuff for a C/(C++) project that was developed for MSVC. I need to port it to g++ / MinGw. There is a library (DLL) that was build with VS. I can not get this library to link with the rest of the code, i always get undefined reference errors. It seems that the name mangeling between MSVC and g++ not compatible. Unfortunately I can not recompile the library with g++ because it uses some Microsoft Stuff that is incompatible with g++ (MFC/AFX).

So I wonder if there is any way to tell g++ to replace all undefined references with simple stub functions that just return 0 or Null.

Because I dont really need any of the functions, and I won't even call functions that call any of the missing functions. I just want to have something there so that the project compiles without changing the code that i want to test.

Is there any way to do that? Is there a tool that maybe extracts all the exposed functions and creates a replacement lib that only contains the stub functions?

Comment: Couldn't you create a separate object file with empty functions of the correct names compiled with GCC and link that in too?

Comment: I probably could, but the library is pretty large and I dont know how to find all the signatures that it exposes. I wonder if there is a tool that could help.

Comment: You might be able to parse the linker error messages and extract a list of missing function names that way and possibly even automatically output a source file from that contains blank function definitions of the missing functions.

Comment: In Windows external symbols must be resolved. So just having the library file without the symbols won't work. If your dependency library is open source you should try to build it with the same compiler.